# How to filter Products through attributes (color, size etc.) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and want to filter out specific products.

I have two tables in my Database, the first one is table `products` and the second one is table `attributes`.

**Products Table**

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->BigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('code');
  $table->integer('status')->default(1);
  $table->integer('featured')->default(1);
  $table->string('image');
  $table->longText('short_description');
  $table->longText('long_description');
  $table->timestamps();
})
```

**Product Attributes Table**

```
Schema::create('product_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {. 
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
  $table->string('sku');
  $table->string('size'); 
  $table->string('color');
  $table->string('price');
  $table->string('stock');
  $table->timestamps();
})
```

**Relationship**

As i have multiple attributes of single product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function attributes()
    {
         return $this->hasmany('App\Models\ProductAttributes', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

**MY Blade file**

```
<form action="{{url('/product/filter')}}" method="post">
 @csrf
<input type="hidden"value="{{$slug}}"name="slug">

<div
  class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
   <input name="color" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="black" value="black">   <label class="custom-control-label" for="black">Black</label>
</div>

</form>
```

I have a function in my controller

```
public function shop()
{

$filter_products = Product::with('attributes')->where(['category_id' => $category->id, 'color' => $request->color]);

    return view('frontend.shop', compact('filter_products'));
}
```

After applying this function i got no result

Please guide me how can I filter products at my frontend shop page according to specific size or color.
and what code will be in shop function.

please reply i will be very thankful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need filter by the relationship, take a look in the documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

By example
Using WhereHas

```
$filter_products = Product::with('attributes')
   ->where(['category_id' => $category->id])
   ->whereHas('attributes',function($query) use($request){
      $query->where(['color' => $request->color]);
   });
```

If in the with there is no where applied this will return all the attributes

You can use the same filter applied in whereHas to with to prevent this behaviour

```
$filter_products = Product::with(['attributes'=>function($query) use($request){
        $query->where(['color' => $request->color]);
    }])
    ->where(['category_id' => $category->id])
    ->whereHas('attributes',function($query) use($request){
        $query->where(['color' => $request->color]);
    });
```

Comment: Added some suggestions corrections.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $brands         = Brand::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
    $colors         = Color::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
    $sizes          = Size::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
    $weights        = Weight::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
    $tags           = Tag::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
    try{
        if (!empty($_GET['colors']) || !empty($_GET['brands']) || !empty($_GET['sizes']) || !empty($_GET['weights']) || !empty($_GET['tags'])) {
            $products = Product::where( function($query ){
                $query->when(!empty(request()->colors) ,function($subquery){
                    $subquery->whereHas('colors', function($subquery)  {
                        $subquery->whereIn('colors.id',request()->colors);
                    });
                })->when(!empty(request()->sizes) ,function($subquery){
                    $subquery->whereHas('sizes', function($subquery)  {
                        $subquery->whereIn('sizes.id',request()->sizes);
                    });
                })->when(!empty(request()->weights) ,function($subquery){
                    $subquery->whereHas('weights', function($subquery)  {
                        $subquery->whereIn('weights.id',request()->weights);
                    });
                })->when(!empty(request()->tags) ,function($subquery){
                    $subquery->whereHas('tags', function($subquery)  {
                        $subquery->whereIn('tags.id',request()->tags);
                    });
                })->when(!empty(request()->brands) ,function($subquery){
                    $subquery->whereHas('brand', function($subquery)  {
                        $subquery->whereIn('brand_id',request()->brands);
                    });
                })->when(!empty(request()->is_new) ,function($subquery){
                    $subquery->where('is_new',request()->is_new);
                })->when(!empty(request()->gender) ,function($subquery){
                    $subquery->where('gender', 'LIKE', "%" . request()->gender . "%");
                });
            })->paginate(10);
        
            
            return view('front.shop',compact('products','brands','colors','sizes','weights','tags'));
        } else {
            return  redirect()->route('products');
        }
        
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        toastr()->error(trans('Some thing is wrong please try again'));
        return  redirect()->route('products');
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).